# How can I compare the next character which the file contains?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am getting few problems when reading code. This is the text file.

```
2X^6+3X^3+4X^0=0
5X^6+X^2+X^1-4X^0=0
```

I am getting a proper input for the first line but in second line first I need to ignore. I searched here and found how to use it and it's work to get to next line ignoring all the left over characters of first line.

You can see in second line with **X** there is no integer, now problem is the second while loop is running continuously. If I add **1** in text file with the X the file reads perfectly. Also how can I put a condition to satisfy this that when there is directly **X** or **-X**, it should store **1** or **-1** and goes to next character? Also you can see **^** I have to store this in a variable whereas I should ignore it but didn't how to ignore it?

Thanks in advance

```
int main()
{
int in;
int power;
char x;
char f;
fstream fin;
fin.open("input1.txt");
list l1,l2;

while(fin.peek() != 61)
{
        fin>>in;
        fin>>x;
        fin>>f;
        fin>>power;
        cout<<in<<endl<<x<<endl<<f<<endl<<power<<endl;
        l1.addtoend(in,power,x);
        cout<<endl;
}
fin.ignore(2,'\n');

while(fin.peek() != 61)
{
        fin>>in;
        fin>>x;
        fin>>f;
        fin>>power;
        cout<<in<<endl<<x<<endl<<f<<endl<<power<<endl;
        l2.addtoend(in,power,x);
        cout<<endl;
}
l1.display();
l2.display();
}
```

Comment: Read the entire line in as a string and parse the string, breaking it down into its components.  Messing around with `operator >>` and `peek` calls to do this isn't the way it should be done.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzle I know that way but it will need lot of conditions to get the right inputs.

Comment: *I know that way* -- That *is* the way to do this. -- *but it will need lot of conditions to get the right input* -- LOL.  That is exactly what you will wind up doing -- that's the nature of the task.  Tokenization, using a regular expression, parsing, etc.  That's how this all works.  You are expecting input routines to parse your string -- again, it is almost never done in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not so simple as expected.

We need to split up the task into smaller parts.

What you want to do, is splitting your equation in terms and extract from this the coefficients and exponents.

Splitting up something in similar parts is also called tokenizing.

So, your equation consists of terms, which all follow the same pattern. First an optional sign, followed by the coefficients, then a “X^”, and, at the end the exponent (which may or may not have a sign).

And since all terms have the same pattern, we can find them with a so-called regex.  C++ supports this functionality. Also for splitting up a text in smaller tokens/terms/pattern-matches, we have a special iterator `std::sregex_token_iterator`. Like any other iterator in C++, it iterates over the source string and extracts (and copies) all matched patterns.

OK, then we found already a solution for the first sub task. Extract all terms and put them into a `std::vector`. We will use the `std::vector`s range constructor, to do this, while defining the variable.

The next step is to get the coefficient. Here we need some special handling, because the coefficient can be omitted with an assumed 1. Using this assumption, we will read the term and convert the coefficient to an integer. And because we want to do that in one statement, we use `std::transform` from the STL’s algorithm library.

Getting the exponents is easier. We simply convert anything in a term following the ‘^’-sign to an integer. We again use `std::transform` to work on all terms in one statement.

Last but not least, we will get the right-hand-side of the equation and convert it also to an integer.

Please note:

All this can be done also with float type values
We could also allow spaces in the equation

For that, we would simple modify the `std::regex`-string.

Please see the complete example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    std::string equation{ "5X^6+X^2+X^1-4X^0=0" };

    const std::regex re(R"(([+-]?\d?X\^[+-]?\d+))");
    std::vector<std::string> terms{ std::sregex_token_iterator(equation.begin(), equation.end(), re,1),std::sregex_token_iterator() };


    std::vector<int> coefficients(terms.size());
    std::vector<int> exponents(terms.size());
    int rightHandSite{ 0 };

    // Everything in front of X is the coefficient. Handle special case, when no digit is given
    std::transform(terms.begin(), terms.end(), coefficients.begin(), [](const std::string& s) {
        std::string temp = s.substr(0U, s.find('X'));
        if (1 == temp.size() && !std::isdigit(temp[0])) temp += '1';
        return std::stoi(temp); });

    // Get all exponents
    std::transform(terms.begin(), terms.end(), exponents.begin(), [](const std::string & s) {
        return std::stoi(s.substr(s.find('^') + 1)); });

    // Get right Hand site of equation
    rightHandSite = std::stoi(equation.substr(equation.find('=') + 1));

    // Show result
    std::cout << "\nEquation: " << equation << "\n\nFound '" << terms.size() << "' terms.\n\nCoeffient  Exponent\n";
    for (size_t i = 0U; i < terms.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << std::right << std::setw(9) << coefficients[i] << std::setw(10) << exponents[i] << "\n";
    std::cout << "\n                  --> " << rightHandSite << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

There are many other possible solutions. But maybe it will give you some idea on what you could do.